# Kendo UI Jquery ContextMenu inside Kendo UI ListView

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview, kendo-contextmenu

I am trying to use a kendo ui contextMenu on kendo ui listView items but it does work , and there is no error.

```
//The ListView HTML
<div id="listView"></div>
<div id="pager" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>

 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <div class="document">
            <img width="65px" height="65px" src="../Content/extensionsIcon/#=FileExtension#.png" alt="#: DocTitle #" />
            <h5>#:DocTitle#</h5>
        </div>
    </script>

 //The ContextMenu HTML 
 <ul id="context-menu">
<li id="download">Download</li>
<li id="remove">Remove</li>
</ul>


 $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
    target: "#listView .document",
    select: function (e) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the context menu [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/context-menu). You should use the [filter](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu/configuration/filter) property of context menu.

```
      $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
                    target: "#listView",
                    filter: ".document",                    
                    select: function(e) {
                        // Do something on select
                    }
       });
```